# fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! A tour of go - Webcrawler

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I'm trying to [this](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10) exercise from the tour of go. My solution is provided below but i am getting a deadlock error. Any idea what's causing this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

var (
    mutex sync.Mutex
    waitG sync.WaitGroup
    cache = make(map[string]bool)
)

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if cache[url]{
        mutex.Lock()
        fmt.Println("Duplicate: ", url)
        mutex.Unlock()
        return
    }
        mutex.Lock()
        fmt.Println("None-duplicate: ", url)
        cache[url] = true
        mutex.Unlock()
    
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        waitG.Add(1)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return

    waitG.Done()
}

func main() {
    waitG.Add(1)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    waitG.Wait()
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Panic Im getting:

```
Duplicate:  https://golang.org/
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x0)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x25
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x49a702)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x71
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox943974961/prog.go:58 +0x55
```

Comment: The `waitG.Done()` in your `Crawl` func is after the call to `return`??

Answer (score 0):

Your `waitG.Wait()` would wait forever because the waitGroup is never notified of completion (using e.g. `waitG.Done()`). The Go runtime is smart enough to detect this situation and issue a panic.

There are a number of problems in the code leading to this situation:

1. Unreachable code:

   ```
        return          // *Nothing* happens after a return!
        waitG.Done()    // this line will never execute.
   ```

   (pay attention to compiler warnings - most compilers will warn about unreachable code)
2. Missing the calls to `waitG.Done()` in error paths:

   ```
    if cache[url]{
        mutex.Lock()
        fmt.Println("Duplicate: ", url)
        mutex.Unlock()
        return          // oops forgot to call waitG.Done() !!!
    }
   ```

   (the same applies to other error paths)

The best solution to this is to [**defer**](https://gobyexample.com/defer) the call to `waitG.Done()` at the beginning of the function:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    defer waitG.Done()   // look ma, no need to worry about this later !!!
    // ... rest of the code ...
```

And now [it works](https://play.golang.org/p/gW5HkxCVbU0).